Torchscript failure: 'RecursiveScriptModule' object has no attribute
I am trying to use PyTorch's Torchscript to script a module defined in a third-party library.
The example below is an abstract version of the problem. Suppose some library I cannot modify defines SomeClass and LibraryModule classes, where the latter is a PyTorch module.
LibraryModule's main method is compute, which takes a tensor and an instance of SomeClass.
import torch
import torch.nn as nn


class SomeClass:
    """A utility class in a library I cannot modify"""
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x


class LibraryModule(nn.Module):
    """A module provided in a library I cannot modify"""
    def __init__(self, in_features, out_features):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(in_features, out_features)

    def compute(self, x, some_class_object: SomeClass):
        """
        Main function of my module; like forward, but takes a non-tensor argument
        """
        return self.linear(x) * some_class_object.x

This is what I tried to get a script for the class:
script = torch.jit.script(LibraryModule(3, 2))
print(script.compute(torch.tensor([10, 20, 30]), SomeClass(2)))

but I get the following error:
  File "torchscript.py", line 25, in <module>
    print(script.compute(torch.tensor([10, 20, 30]), SomeClass(2)))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "\Lib\site-packages\torch\jit\_script.py", line 826, in __getattr__
    return super().__getattr__(attr)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "Lib\site-packages\torch\jit\_script.py", line 533, in __getattr__
    return super().__getattr__(attr)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1931, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: 'RecursiveScriptModule' object has no attribute 'compute'. Did you mean: 'compile'?

I also tried scripting the method directly:
compute_script = torch.jit.script(LibraryModule(3, 2).compute)
print(compute_script(torch.tensor([10, 20, 30]), SomeClass(2)))

but then I get:
RuntimeError: 
'Tensor (inferred)' object has no attribute or method 'linear'.:
  File "torchscript.py", line 21
        Main function of my module; like forward, but takes a non-tensor argument
        """
        return self.linear(x) * some_class_object.x
               ~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- HERE

How can I get a working script of LibraryModule.compute?

The error
AttributeError: 'RecursiveScriptModule' object has no attribute 'compute'

is caused by the fact that only forward and other methods forward eventually calls recursively are scripted (compiled) by default. Since compute is not called by forward, it is not included in the scripted module. To do so, one must decorate it with @torch.jit.export.
Because I cannot change the original library, I can create a wrapper module whose forward method calls LibraryModule.compute:
class WrapperModule(nn.Module):
    """A wrapper module that uses the library module"""
    def __init__(self, in_features, out_features):
        super().__init__()
        self.lib = LibraryModule(in_features, out_features)

    def forward(self, x, some_class_object: SomeClass):
        return self.lib.compute(x, some_class_object)


script = torch.jit.script(WrapperModule(3, 2))
print(script(torch.tensor([10., 20., 30.]), SomeClass(torch.tensor(2))))

This works, although note that I also needed to change the main tensor's type to float, and needed to pass a tensor to SomeClass.
The second error shown in my question is somewhat unrelated. When I call
torch.jit.script(LibraryModule(3, 2).compute)

somehow the reference to self gets lost and I can't access self.linear anymore. This is odd since LibraryModule(3, 2).compute should be a closure capturing self, but perhaps this is a Torchscript quirk (note how the code below works fine):
f = LibraryModule(3, 2).compute
print(f(torch.tensor([10., 20., 30.]), SomeClass(torch.tensor(2))))

